# Why the process after the return is not processed in Controller Codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am developing an application with the help of another website API. In the scheme in one process I have to respond to the sign that I am receiving data details and in one state must send GET requests to their API again

[this is the schme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxkgg.png)

my code is like this

```
public function confirm(){
        $result = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

        return $this->output
                    ->set_content_type('application/json')
                    ->set_status_header(200)
                    ->set_output(json_encode(array(
                        'status' => 'OK',
                        'message' => 'Message from merchant if any'
                    )));

        //kirim get untuk confirm order
        $url = $this->ci->config->item("kredivo_api_link_confirm");

        //load libary kredivo
        $this->load->library('CoreKredivo','corekredivo');

        //sent to v2/update
        $confirm_order = array(
            'transaction_id' => 'e75e5b62-5432-4d72-98b4-c5e938c6fbd9',
            'signature_key'  => 'a7Ijx%2FWgv02I4rvPQSld07uQO9TNMHg%2FFcJsS7EhA2GRKLgKiiYbYrHaLiuMKcG4cG98Iw0vTOPUgeHOZsPhqv3wvAGKgMDgEEMxMmZS3uXG0JIOzdFQc5s0zJ5qlhKZ',
        );

        //kirim data ke confirmation core kredivo
        $confirmation = $this->corekredivo->confirmOrder($url,$confirm_order);

        //menerima data dari core kredivo dan melakukan decode
        $finalResponse_payment = json_decode($confirmation,true);

        //untuk check
        $data = array(
            '_content' => 'shop/kredivo_2',
            '_title' => 'Tes Konfirmasi',
            '_respon' => $finalResponse_payment
        );
```

the problem is when I make a return in this section

```
return $this->output
                    ->set_content_type('application/json')
                    ->set_status_header(200)
                    ->set_output(json_encode(array(
                        'status' => 'OK',
                        'message' => 'Message from merchant if any'
                    )));
```

the process below is not executed, what is the cause? and maybe there are suggestions

Comment: Your return statement (2nd instruction in your function) will cause the function to exit, returning the value you have assigned. So all the code below it will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The return keyword stops the function's execution and *returns* back to the method calling it. Everything written below a return statement is ignored.